# Photoshop Fonts Always Italic

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, microsoft-expression

I've recently exported an image from Microsoft Expression Design to a `.psd` format, but when I open the exported `.psd` & attempt to create a new font layer, any font I choose will be italicized but only slightly.  I'm positive that my font style is not set to be italicized, and when I select `Italic` the font will become visibly more italic.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

As you can see, the only difference is the font size (though the one on the right side is set to Regular, regular is simply a bolder looking lig

Answer (score 18, accepted):

More than likely Photoshop is setting all your fonts to be italic.

Simply go to `Window -> Character`

A box should pop up that looks like this:

[image]

Make sure that the second icon (the one I highlighted in red) is not clicked.

Photoshop comes with fake bold/italic settings to provide fonts that don't naturally support it with those settings. But if that setting gets turned on, it'll stay on until it's turned off. As you can see in my screenshot, the font still says "Regular" even though the fake italics is pressed.